# rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i am trying to run the cmd i am geting the fallowing error

Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":10.0".

python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server

i was fallowing ur tutorial it would be a great help if u can rply asap

i am running ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual sys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173383/rosrun-rqt_graph-rqt_graph/) by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-06-12**:
are you calling ssh with -XY flags?

**Comment by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on 2014-06-12**:
i am very new to this i was following ros tutorial when i used this cmd i got that error. from last 2 days i am trying really hard for a solution

this was the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_graph is a graphical tool, and it sounds like you're trying to run it on a system that doesn't have a window manager.

Do other graphical programs work?

If you can provide more information about your setup, such as if you system has a graphical display, and/or if you're trying to use X forwarding over ssh, the community might be able to provide more help.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on 2014-06-12**:
tq for ur rply it has a graphical display nvidia 512mb   and using ssh

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-13**:
Do other graphical programs work?

**Comment by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on 2014-06-14**:
tell me a program name i will check and tell u

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-14**:
gedit is simple graphical text editor, it should be a simple test to see if the basic gui functionality is working.

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-09-26**:
Hello there. I'm having a similar problem:

```
sergio@remotepc:~$ rqt_graph
python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :5.
```

I'm working remotely over a ssh conection using **TurboVNC**. With**vglrun** from **VirtualGL**, I manage to run **Gazebo** & **Rviz**...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-30**:
My best guess is that your VNC server doesn't support some obscure X feature that rqt_graph is using. You may want to try using plain ssh X forwarding instead.

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-10-09**:
Uhm, I see. Thank you for your suggestion. Still, using Putty and connecting to the remote host with X forwarding I get the same error...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-09**:
I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-12-03**:
Finally I got it working via MobaXterm_Personal_7.2 ! I can now see the rqt_graph and rqt_tools windows via ssh with MOBA. You could try it =). Cheers and thanks for the help.